# Убрать точку и цифры после неё (сумма без копеек)

Tags: javascript

Дано:

```
&("#window #summa").html(tr_free.act['summ']);
```

Выводит сумму с копейками 800.8

Задача получить цифру без копеек 800

Делаю так:

```
&("#window #summa").html(tr_free.act['summ'].split('.')[0].replace(/\D+/g,""));
```

или так:

```
&("#window #summa").html(tr_free.act['summ'].replace(/\D+/g,""));
```

Ничего не выводится. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `Math.round(tr_free.act['summ'])`

Comment: &("#window #summa").html(Math.round(tr_free.act['summ'])); так?

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!

Comment: Но это округление в большую сторону, было бы лучше просто отсечь лишнее)

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите подробнее [про округления](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#okruglenie)

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать вот так:

```js
let floatNumber = 800.8;

console.log(parseInt(floatNumber));
```